# Why don't we need volatile with StampedLock?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, volatile, memory-barriers

Given a code sample from Oracle docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/StampedLock.html

```
class Point {
   private double x, y;
   private final StampedLock sl = new StampedLock();

   void move(double deltaX, double deltaY) { // an exclusively locked method
     long stamp = sl.writeLock();
     try {
       x += deltaX;
       y += deltaY;
     } finally {
       sl.unlockWrite(stamp);
     }
   }

   double distanceFromOrigin() { // A read-only method
     long stamp = sl.tryOptimisticRead();
     double currentX = x, currentY = y;
     if (!sl.validate(stamp)) {
        stamp = sl.readLock();
        try {
          currentX = x;
          currentY = y;
        } finally {
           sl.unlockRead(stamp);
        }
     }
     return Math.sqrt(currentX * currentX + currentY * currentY);
   }

   void moveIfAtOrigin(double newX, double newY) { // upgrade
     // Could instead start with optimistic, not read mode
     long stamp = sl.readLock();
     try {
       while (x == 0.0 && y == 0.0) {
         long ws = sl.tryConvertToWriteLock(stamp);
         if (ws != 0L) {
           stamp = ws;
           x = newX;
           y = newY;
           break;
         }
         else {
           sl.unlockRead(stamp);
           stamp = sl.writeLock();
         }
       }
     } finally {
       sl.unlock(stamp);
     }
   }
 }
```

And provided that all methods of class Point might be called from different threads:

**Why exactly do we not need fields x and y to be declared as volatile?**

Is it guaranteed that the code executing the `Point#moveIfAtOrigin` method would always see the freshest changes to the x and y fields after acquiring `StampedLock#readLock`?

Is there any kind of memory barrier being established when we call `StampedLock#writeLock`, `StampedLock#readLock`?

Could anyone point to a quote from documentation regarding that?

Comment: *Generally speaking* acquiring and releasing locks does create a memory barrier, so any access to variables done inside locks (whether a `StampedLock` or something else) would ensure visibility.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html  scroll down to "Memory Consistency Properties" for the guarantees and the important bit - "The methods of all classes in java.util.concurrent and its subpackages extend these guarantees to higher-level synchronization. In particular: [...]"

Comment: @pvg Thanks for citing the docs, it should do for a formal proof.

Comment: @DmitryGorbunov there's a bit of a meta-answer to this since there are many variants of this question on SO, all slightly different, involving different classes of java.util.concurrent - the full set of guarantees and references to the JMM/JLS are lengthy and they're not repeated in the docs of every class let alone every method but they are outlined in the package (and subpackage docs). So if you run across something like this, that's the first (not-entirely-obvious) place to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell why that is not explicitly cited in the doc - may be because it is sort of implied, but internally that does a `Unsafe.compareAndSwapLong` which translates to `LOCK CMPXCHG`, which on `x86` has `full memory barrier` (I assume something like this is done on other platforms); so there is no need for those to be `volatile` indeed.

Actually any instruction on `x86` that has a `lock` will have a full memory barrier.

Comment: It is explicitly cited in the doc.

Comment: @Eugene That should do for an explanation. Updated your answer to include citation from the page referenced by pvg. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The Javadoc of the [`Lock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) interface states the following:

> **Memory Synchronization**
>
> All Lock implementations must enforce the same memory synchronization semantics as provided by the built-in monitor lock, as described in The Java Language Specification (17.4 Memory Model):
>
> A successful lock operation has the same memory synchronization effects as a successful Lock action.
>   A successful unlock operation has the same memory synchronization effects as a successful Unlock action.
>   Unsuccessful locking and unlocking operations, and reentrant locking/unlocking operations, do not require any memory synchronization effects.

Even though `StampedLock` does not implement `Lock`, it has a method like [`asReadLock()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/StampedLock.html#asReadLock--) that:

> Returns a plain Lock view of this StampedLock in which the Lock.lock() method is mapped to readLock(), and similarly for other methods.

It returns an instance of `StampedLock`'s inner class `ReadLockView`, which IS an actual implementation of `Lock`.

But because it's merely a delegator, that means the original methods must create memory barriers in order to comply with the Memory Synchronization enforcement of the `Lock` interface.

Comment: That wouldn't do for an answer, yet it's a correct and easily understandable conclusion.
I'm not sure why somebody downvoted your post. It definitely adds value. Upvoted it.